# How to save JSON response from user login into Core Data to track the user state in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, core-data

I am trying to save my json response from user login into Core Data, so that when the user quits the app and again opens, it will recognize that specific user. I have only simple json, which is ["String":Any, .... "String":Any] type, now i have saved the response by making model of struct like below, Can anyone know the best way to achieve what i want, Please help me
I am new into Core Data, i have no idea where to start

[image: Here is how i requesting and saving the json]

[image: Here is my LoginInfo model]

[image: Here is my Core Data entity]

Comment: Does ```print(loginData)``` print correct information?

Comment: yess, it will print the login ingo of json

Comment: Post code as text and not as images

Comment: You should start by doing some tutorials and reading some articles on Core Data since stackoverflow is not a tutorial site so this question is to broad and should be closed.

Comment: yeah i read apple doc and their example of how to use CoreData was difficult to understand the concept, So i searched the net of useful tutorials but wasnt successfull, and the last option is to ask a stackoverflow,

Comment: No, stackoverflow is not “the last option” when doing research and/or learning. Also if all you want to achieve is to recognize the user who logged in I am sure UserDefaults would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Fist declare your core data container

```
//CoreData container
private lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "container_name")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            //Error handling
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Here `container_name` would be your core data file name.

Then this function will do the saving:

```
public func saveLoginData(data: LoginData) {
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entityDescription: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "LoginInfo", in: context)!

    let loginInfoEntry: NSManagedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: context)

    //Set your values here
    loginInfoEntry.setValue(data.AccountId, forKey: "accountId")
    loginInfoEntry.setValue(data.UserId, forKey: "userId")
    ... //Set all your values

    //Then save
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        //Error handling
    }
}
```

For query back your data:

```
public func getLoginData() -> LoginData? {
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = self. persistentContainer.viewContext
    let loginDataFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "LoginInfo")
    do {
        let fetchedData: [Any] = try context.fetch(loginDataFetchRequest)
        let loginDataObjectArray: = fetchData as! [NSManagedObject]
        let loginDataObject: NSManagedObject = loginDataObjectArray[0]
        var loginData: LoginData = LoginData()
        loginData.AccountId = loginDataObject.value(forKey: "accountId") as! String
        ...//Set all your values
        
        return loginData
        
    } catch {
        //Handle errors
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is just a simple answer for your question to set you towards a direction. Refer CoreData documentation and some other tutorials to have a better understanding. Also make sure to handle all the errors that can rise from above steps. I did not consider each and every scenario where error could occur.

Comment: thanks for your help, but for the query, it is not working, As LoginData is Decodable protocol, it says it throws an error and I cannot create the new instance of LoginData when I query it, is there any way?

Comment: I made an update to the answer. ```var loginData: LoginData = LoginData()```. Can you show the error please

Comment: it says "Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call" in `var loginData: LoginData = LoginData()` i should give a parameter to LoginData() some Decoder, it is error

Comment: Check if values are coming correctly from query using just a ```print(loginDataObject.value(forKey: "accountId") as! String)``` without creating a loginData.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229646/room-for-nilupul-sandeepa-and-ulugbek come to the chat

Answer (score 0):

**The Basics**
Create your Swift Project on XCode and check `Use CoreData`
Make sure to use `import CoreData` on your class heading

**Saving to CoreData**
If your project uses CoreData, you can proceed with the saving function below:

```
func saveLoginDataToCoreData(data: LoginData){

    guard let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let context = appDel!.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "LoginInfo", in: context)!
    let mngdObj = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    
    mngdObj.setValue(data.LoginToken, forKeyPath: "loginToken")
    mngdObj.setValue(data.UserId, forKeyPath: "userId")
    // Add all loginData here...
     
    do { try context.save(); print("LoginData has been saved to CoreData")
    } catch { print("An error has occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)") } }
```

On the other hand, if your project does not use CoreData, you can declare a CoreData container called a "CoreData Stack" (this is automatically included in a project that uses CoreData in AppDelegate). You can put it inside the ViewController class where you need it, or put in onto a UIViewController extension for global usage:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Your_DataModel_Filename")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print("An error has occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

To use:

```
func saveLoginDataToCoreData(data: LoginData){
    
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "LoginInfo", in: context)!
    let mngdObj: NSManagedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
    
    mngdObj.setValue(data.LoginToken, forKeyPath: "loginToken")
    mngdObj.setValue(data.UserId, forKeyPath: "userId")
    // Add all loginData here...
     
    do { try context.save(); print("LoginData has been saved to CoreData")
    } catch { print("An error has occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)") } }
```

**UPDATE: Follow-up Answers**

If you want to use that loginToken or ANY data from LoginData, we can fetch the values we have saved from the CoreData earlier.

To retrieve values efficiently, it is best that you save the LoginToken of the current User first. For easy access, I suggest that you save it in `UserDefaults` upon LOGIN, and just delete it upon logout.

```
func saveCurrentLoginToken(_ token:String){
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(token, forKey: "currentLoginToken")
    defaults.synchronize() }
```

Sample usage:

```
// ...
let currentLoginToken = data.LoginToken
mngdObj.setValue(currentLoginToken, forKeyPath: "loginToken")
self.saveCurrentLoginToken(currentLoginToken)
// ...
```

To retrieve the currentLoginToken:

```
func getCurrentLoginToken() -> String? {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let token = defaults.object(forKey: "currentLoginToken") as? String
    if token != nil { return token! // Return value if not nil
    } else { return nil } // Will return as nil if you haven't save the LoginToken in UserDefaults
}
```

**Fetching A Specific Data**

I made a function that we can use to fetch ANY of the info we have saved earlier:

```
func getAnyValueFromCoreData(_ loginToken:String,_ key:String) -> Any? { // key = data you want to retrieve the value of

    guard let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return nil }
    let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchReq = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "LoginInfo")
    fetchReq.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "loginToken==%@",loginToken)
    
    var anyVal: Any?
    
    do { let result = try context.fetch(fetchReq)
        for data in result {
            let val = data.value(forKey: key)
            // Check if nil to avoid fatal error
            if val != nil { anyVal = val! } else { anyVal = nil } }
    } catch {
        anyVal = nil // Set value to nil in case of error (not always recommended)
        print("An error has occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    return anyVal }
```

Now, for instance, if you want to get the current user's ReturnCode:

```
func getReturnCode() -> Int? {
     let token = getCurrentLoginToken() // retrieve from UserDefaults
     let returnCode = getAnyValueFromCoreData(token!,"returnCode") as? Int
     return returnCode
}
```

To use (in the situation you have described in the comment):

```
func checkReturnCode(){
     let returnCode = getReturnCode()! // catch if nil?
     if returnCode == 0 {
          // show MainPage to User
     } else { }
     // or use Switch Statements for more than two ReturnCodes
     // or to handle error in case of default (nil value)
}
```

*Disclaimer*: I haven't tested the codes above, if you encounter any error, just let me know in the comments.
*Edit*: Updated `fetchReq` and replaced `filterReq` in `getAnyValueFromCoreData()` (self-made functions)

Comment: thanks, it worked fine, but later if i want to use that loginTokens or any data from LoginData, how can I retrieve it? for example in another vc, if returnCode == 0, show main page to user.

Comment: i have updated my answer to address your followup questions. pls let me know if it works

Comment: I think it has some error, I have searched the internet but could not find solution, it says `Cannot find 'fetchEntity' in scope` and `Cannot find 'filterReq' in scope` in `getAnydatafromCoredata()` method

Comment: @Ulugbek, sorry, those were self-made functions i forgot to include. Will update my answer

Comment: Yeah, no worries, I am so thankful for your help, Now by looking code and i understand the flow, I look forward your update,

Comment: @Ulugbek, i've edited my answer, pls let me know how it went

Comment: @Ulugbek, if any of the answers has solved your question, kindly mark it as the answer. Thanks